# When scrolling a tableview back again cells appear blank?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

After loading a tableview with custom cells all looks fine and scrolling down is fine.
When I scroll up the cells above appear blank. They are in fact fully functional as they can still be selected and then they go off to the details pages. 
The code cellForRowAtIndexPath is executed for the returning row and returns the cell as I would expect with the right details. It just isn't displayed.
Any thoughts/help would be appreciated.

The code below is what I have been using.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) {
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell.


    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //name
    NSString *trimmedString = [aBook.Name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = trimmedString;
    //catagory
    NSString *trimmedExperience = [aBook.PrimaryExperience stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if ([trimmedExperience isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.catagoryLabel.text = @"None";
    }
    else if([trimmedExperience isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        cell.catagoryLabel.text = @"Limited";
    }
    else if ([trimmedExperience isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
        cell.catagoryLabel.text = @"Full";

    }
    else {
        cell.catagoryLabel.text = @"";

    }




    cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f",aBook.distance];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you rendering the cells? Are you using Interface Builder or from scratch?

Comment: The cells are rendered from Interface Builder and text is set in cellForRowAtIndexPath - strange thing is that they work beautifully until they scroll out the top.

Comment: Can you show the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Added method to question - cheers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the xib file and how it loaded. To cut out the issue and gain total control the following code was substituted for the IB version of the custom cell.

```
    static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    CGRect nameLabelRect = CGRectMake(15, 5, 200, 15);
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameLabelRect];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    nameLabel.tag = kNameTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [nameLabel release];

    CGRect catagoryLabelRect = CGRectMake(15, 26, 100, 15);
    UILabel *catagoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:catagoryLabelRect];
    catagoryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    catagoryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    catagoryLabel.tag = kExperienceTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:catagoryLabel];
    [catagoryLabel  release];

    CGRect distanceLabelRect = CGRectMake(210, 26, 70, 15);
    UILabel *distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:distanceLabelRect];
    distanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    distanceLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    distanceLabel.tag = kDistanceTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];
    [distanceLabel release];
}
```

Thanks for helping think this one through. Now the scrolling works perfectly.

Comment: Glad you got it working... wonder WHY the xib didn't work, though?